# SecureSocial error after Play 2.0->2.1 migration

Tags: scala, playframework, migration, playframework-2.1, securesocial

I get a tenacious error with SecureSocial after Play 2.0->2.1 migration.

I am using the following dependency:

```
"securesocial" % "securesocial_2.10" % "master-SNAPSHOT",
```

I launched play 2.1.1, entered *clean*, *update* and *compile*.

The following error occurs during compilation:

```
[error] /home/somebody/play/myproject/app/controllers/Application.scala:473: overloaded method value SecuredAction with alternatives:
[error]   (f: securesocial.core.SecuredRequest[play.api.mvc.AnyContent] => play.api.mvc.Result)play.api.mvc.Action[play.api.mvc.AnyContent] <and>
[error]   (ajaxCall: Boolean)(f: securesocial.core.SecuredRequest[play.api.mvc.AnyContent] => play.api.mvc.Result)play.api.mvc.Action[play.api.mvc.AnyContent] <and>
[error]   (authorize: securesocial.core.Authorization)(f: securesocial.core.SecuredRequest[play.api.mvc.AnyContent] => play.api.mvc.Result)play.api.mvc.Action[play.api.mvc.AnyContent] <and>
[error]   (ajaxCall: Boolean,authorize: securesocial.core.Authorization)(f: securesocial.core.SecuredRequest[play.api.mvc.AnyContent] => play.api.mvc.Result)play.api.mvc.Action[play.api.mvc.AnyContent] <and>
[error]   [A](ajaxCall: Boolean, authorize: Option[securesocial.core.Authorization], p: play.api.mvc.BodyParser[A])(f: securesocial.core.SecuredRequest[A] => play.api.mvc.Result)play.api.mvc.Action[A]
[error]  cannot be applied to ()
[error]   def shareKnowledge = SecuredAction() { implicit request =>
[error]                        ^
```

Comment: You'll have to remove the extra `()`. There is no method that takes an empty first parameter. Try with `def shareKnowledge = SecuredAction { implicit request =>`

Comment: Thank you. Now it works. Why is it different to Play 2.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to remove the extra `()`. There is no method that takes an empty first parameter list.

Try with this instead:

```
def shareKnowledge = SecuredAction { implicit request =>
```

---

They seem to have removed the default value for `ajaxCall` so there is no method signature with an empty first parameter list any more.

Look at this commit change for details: https://github.com/jaliss/securesocial/commit/996ec756348c0e150f89358a3d2b447358288609